# Making jQuery autocomplete work with database as source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I'd like to use the autocomplete widget to make a search bar that will go through a userlist which is stored in a database. I'm using MySQL.

I tried the autocomplete with a local source (a JS array), and it works. But with my PHP script, it doesn't.

Why ?

Here's my HTML code :

```
<form method="get" action="" class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="InputSearch">Search Engine</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputSearch" placeholder="Search a member...">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                </div>
</form>
```

Here's my jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $( "#InputSearch" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
});
```

And here's my search.php code :

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$sQuery = "SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$term%'";

$aUsers = DBOperation::queryGetMulti($sQuery);

echo json_encode($aUsers);
```

DBOperation is a class I use for Database queries, in this case it will simply return an array containing every line it reads in subarrays. It has been used in many other cases and works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: May not be related but you should specify the content type header when outputting the search.php json

Comment: I promise you, there *are* tutorials on this stuff.

Comment: do you have it online somewhere? codepen, fiddle, jsbin, your server? many things could go wrong, from db connection to search.php being in some other place than you think giving 404 etc. it's pretty much impossible to diagnose given the info that you provided.

Comment: Why are you nesting `$(function() {` inside  `$(document).ready(function() {` -> `$(document).ready(function() { $(function() {`? They do the same thing, only 1 is necessary. Also, `dataType` is not an option in `autocomplete` -> http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ as it required when using a string as the `source` -> http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source. Have you tried accessing `search.php?term=???` directly in your browser to see if your page returns valid results? Finally check your browser console to see if there are any error in your javascript code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answser.

My code had many problems. My javascript was fine (except for the double $(function()). My search.php couldn't find DBOperation as it wasn't included for some reason, so I had to include it manually.

Also, had to make another associative array to properly return "value:name" to jQuery, otherwise it wouldn't work. The final code of the PHP file is on my GitHub at https://github.com/Nestecha

Thanks again !